# JWT Claim based routing with OpenShift ServiceMesh not working

Tags: openshift, istio, servicemesh

I'm trying to perform some basic JWT claim based routing leveraging OpenShift Service Mesh. OpenShift version is 4.6.23. RedHat OpenShift Service Mesh version is 2.1.1-0.

Below is the ServiceMeshControlPlane resource I use to setup ServiceMesh on the OCP cluster :

```yaml
apiVersion: maistra.io/v2
kind: ServiceMeshControlPlane
metadata:
  name: basic
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  version: v2.0
  tracing:
    type: Jaeger
    sampling: 10000
  addons:
    jaeger:
      name: jaeger
      install:
        storage:
          type: Memory
    kiali:
      enabled: true
      name: kiali
    grafana:
      enabled: true
```

Basically, I tried to follow this [Istio documentation page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/jwt-route/) to test the JWT claim routing

Here is the structure of the JWT token I'm using :

```json
{
    "iss": "https://eu-de.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/6f631e4d-7ecc-4a1c-8cf8-ea2d0a5c32e6",
    "exp": 1646244105,
    "aud": [
        "f7f1e8bf-72d0-4e7d-90ff-cb76a8079c46"
    ],
    "sub": "99bb916e-8f99-4e0a-8b1f-72c2171448d1",
    "email_verified": true,
    "amr": [
        "cloud_directory"
    ],
    "iat": 1646240505,
    "tenant": "6f631e4d-7ecc-4a1c-8cf8-ea2d0a5c32e6",
    "scope": "openid appid_default appid_readuserattr appid_readprofile appid_writeuserattr appid_authenticated",
    "roles": [
        "teamA"
    ]
}
```

The RequestAuthentication definition :

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: jwt-auth
  namespace: sample-mesh
spec:
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "https://eu-de.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/6f631e4d-7ecc-4a1c-8cf8-ea2d0a5c32e6"
    jwksUri: "https://eu-de.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/6f631e4d-7ecc-4a1c-8cf8-ea2d0a5c32e6/publickeys"
```

And the definition of the VirtualService that is supposed to handle the routing :

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: catalog
spec:
  hosts:
  - '*'
  gateways:
  - sample-mesh-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        "@request.auth.claims.roles":
          exact: teamA
    route:
    - destination:
        host: catalog
        subset: version-v1
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: catalog
        subset: version-v2
```

I would then expect the trafic to be routed to the catalog v1 when the `roles` claim contains the value `teamA`. But in practice, I observe that the trafic is always routed to catalog v2 even if the token has the required value in the claim.

Is there anything I missed in the configuration ?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Which version of Istio did you use and how exactly did you set up your cluster?

Comment: Actually, I'm using RedHat OpenShift ServiceMesh and not the base Istio. The setup has been done by installing several operators (ElasticSearch/Kiali/OpenTracing/ServiceMesh) on the cluster and then creating a ServiceMeshControlPlane resource I added to my post.

Comment: From what I understand, OpenShift Service Mesh 2.1 embeds Istio 1.9.8. The JWT claim based routing feature seems to have been introduced in Istio 1.12.x ...